# Vlookup: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

Update on 19/9/2015:
To address the issue raised, I split the sub into three sections.

1. To copy the file from one place to another
2. To convert (using save-as method) xls to xlsx. The file can be opened.
3. vlookup the value and print it on designated cell.

I managed to get the first 2 tasks done, with the second task from the help:
[Batch convert .xls to .xlsx with VBA without opening the workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167539/batch-convert-xls-to-xlsx-with-vba-without-opening-the-workbooks)

However, the error pop up: subscript out of range when I run the

---

Previously:

Hi This is the first time for me to ask a question and I had tried my very best to adhere to the tips and guidelines given. 
Note: Assume the macro perform in a.xlsx

I wrote this macro to:

1. Copy a file (abc.xls) from path A
2. Paste the file (abc.xls) to path B
3. Rename the file from abc.xls to abc.xlsx
4. Perform vlookup to look for the value in abc.xlsx and return the value in a.xlsx 's designated cell.

---

```
Sub CopyFile()
    Dim FSO
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sSFolder As String
    Dim sDFolder As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wbk As Workbook

     ' Get the number of times to loop from Cell D2
    NumLoop = Cells(2, "D")

    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "NumLoop" number of times.

    For i = 1 To NumLoop
    ' This is the file name, examle "LBF-010114.xls"
    sFile = Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "AG")

    'This is the source file's path/location, example" D:\users\destop\A\"
    sSFolder = Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "AD")

    'this is the destination file's path, example" D:\users\destop\B\"
    sDFolder = Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "AF")

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True

    'Just a check point to see if the code executed until this point
    Cells(i + 5, "E") = "File Exist"

    Else
    MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
    End If

    Next

End Sub

Sub ConvertAllFile()

'I refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167539/batch-convert-xls-to-xlsx-with-vba-without-opening-the-workbooks
'All credits go to them

    Dim strCurrentFileExt   As String
    Dim strNewFileExt       As String
    Dim objFSO              As Object
    Dim objFolder           As Object
    Dim objFile             As Object
    Dim xlFile              As Workbook
    Dim strNewName          As String
    Dim strFolderPath       As String

    strCurrentFileExt = ".xls"
    strNewFileExt = ".xlsx"

    strFolderPath = "D:\Users\COM_GSY.APLIFEISGREAT\Desktop\LBF Fund\"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.getfolder(strFolderPath)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        strNewName = objFile.Name
        If Right(strNewName, Len(strCurrentFileExt)) = strCurrentFileExt Then
            Set xlFile = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path, , True)
            strNewName = Replace(strNewName, strCurrentFileExt, strNewFileExt)
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Select Case strNewFileExt
            Case ".xlsx"
                xlFile.SaveAs strFolderPath & strNewName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Case ".xlsm"
                xlFile.SaveAs strFolderPath & strNewName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            End Select
            xlFile.Close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next objFile

ClearMemory:
    strCurrentFileExt = vbNullString
    strNewFileExt = vbNullString
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set xlFile = Nothing
    strNewName = vbNullString
    strFolderPath = vbNullString

End Sub

Sub PrintNAV()

Dim i As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim FSO

NumLoop = Cells(2, "D")

For i = 1 To NumLoop

'Get the file name
sFile = Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "AG")

'Set the file path
FilePath = "D:\Users\COM_GSY.APLIFEISGREAT\Desktop\LBF Fund\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FileExists(FilePath & sFile) Then
Cells(i + 5, "B") = Application.WorksheetFunction.vLookUp(Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "N"), Workbooks(FilePath & sFile).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L120"), 12, False)
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

---

I checked on some of the comments in the forum here, it was said that it is possible to perform vlookup for closed excel workbook so long it is xlsx format. Not sure how true is that.

Again, I would appreciate any comment to help up.

Comment: `Name sDFolder & sFile As sDFolder & Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "AI")` You just can't rename an `xls` file to `.xlsx` directly. I mean you can rename but it will not be a valid xlsx file

Comment: `FileName = Sheets("Data Pointer").cell(i + 2, "AI")` You are missing `s` in `Cell`

Comment: `Cells(i + 5, "C").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "AI"), Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L120"), 2, 0)` You are referring to the new  file as `Workbooks(FileName)` but that workbook is not even open yet. Fix all these 3 things I mentioned and then we will take it form there

Comment: When you concatenate `sSFolder & sFile` and `sDFolder & sFile` there is no connecting backslash (e.g. `Chr(92)`) according to the samples in the comments.

Comment: @Jeeped: I thought about that too but I guess OP has that sepcified in the cell `Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "AG")` since the files are getting renamed correctly :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might have been a typo in the comment. If the  `FSO.CopyFile` was working, that bears out as a destination with folder only has to end in a backslash.

Comment: @SiddharthRout , thanks for you help. I managed to address the issues raised by you. Only the part where the excel file has to be opened before performing vlookup. This is because I saw some of the comments from forum saying that it is possible to perform vlookup for closed excel workbook so long it is xlsx format. Not sure how true is that. Also, to clear your confusion, there is a backslash in the string already. Thanks again, peeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Workbooks Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224505%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is *"A collection of all the Workbook objects that are currently open in the Microsoft Excel application."*. It does not include workbooks that are on your hard drive and not open.

If you are absolutely determined to access a closed workbook then write the formula to the worksheet cell to take care of the bridge to an unopened workbook. By evaluating a native worksheet formula on the open worksheet, you shouldn't have to open the external workbook. You can remove the formula by reverting it to its returned value.

```
dim extVLOOKUP as string
If FSO.FileExists(FilePath & sFile) Then
    With Sheets("Data Pointer")
        extVLOOKUP = "=VLOOKUP(""" & .Cells(i + 2, "N") & """, '" & FilePath & "[" & sFile & "]Sheet1'!$A:$L, 12, FALSE)"
        'Debug.Print extVLOOKUP  '<~~ uncomment to check the formula
        '.Cells(i + 5, "B") = Application.Evaluate(extVLOOKUP)
        .Cells(i + 5, "B").Formula = extVLOOKUP
        .Cells(i + 5, "B") = .Cells(i + 5, "B").Value
    End With
End If
```

I've wrapped the value from Sheets("Data Pointer").Cells(i + 2, "N") in quotes just like a text value would have to be wrapped in quotes on a worksheet formula. If it is a number, the quotes can (and probably should) be removed.

Comment: I will get the code run again on Monday and give an update to this.

Comment: it works! Thanks @Jeeped. Value from cell (i+2 , "N") are not numbers. So, i leave the quotes as it is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just realised you don't have to convert file to xlsx to perform the vlookup. Yet another great news.